# Heroku deploy build failure for Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, heroku

I have a Spring Boot REST API locally.

It is successfully generating the .war file locally when I run mvn clean package.

Now I want to deploy it to Heroku.

These are the steps I've done.

1. Uploded the code to a github respository. Let's say \myrestapi.
2. Opened a terminal to run Heroku CLI commands
3. Logged in heroku

   `heroku login`
4. Ran command to create the app on heroku

   `heroku create myrestapi`

   This command didn't work. Got the message saying the name "myrestapi" already existed.

   So I changed the name to something else. Let's say "cl-myrestapi":

   `heroku create cl-myrestapi`

   It ran successfully.
5. Ran command to create the free postgreSQL database on heroku:

   `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`
6. Git push

   `git push heroku main`

   This starts downloads successfully.

   But then generates the following error:

```
    remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    remote:        [INFO] Total time:  14.653 s
    remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-19T18:43:12Z
    remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-
    compile) on project myrestapi: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
    remote:        [ERROR]
    remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    remote:        [ERROR]
    remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following artic
    les:
    remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    remote:
    remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
    remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
    remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: e11a85238783f54ee30765ba4f8a55354930be
    09
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version e11a85238783f54ee30765ba4f
    8a55354930be09
    remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
    remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to cl-myrestapi.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/cl-myrestapi.git
     ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/cl-myrestapi.git'
```

Why am I getting this error since it is building successfully locally?

There are only two differences I can see:

1. The need to have a different project name on heroku (see step 4 above)
2. Application.properties is different.

This is my original application.properties (that runs locally).

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myrestapi
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=yyy
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This is the updated application.properties (being uploaded to heroku)

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

UPATE:
Noted that when the `git push heroku main` command is executed, at the begining it says "Installing jdk 1.8", while I'm using version 11.

So that seems to be the issue.

To solve that I tried to add a System.properties file at the root with the following line:

`java.runtime.version=11`

But didn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

- First Don't forget to add this in `pom.xml`

```xml
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
```

- Second, check project SDK and project language level (in project structure) both of them should be 11.

Check `Java compiler` in settings and make sure that `project-byte-code-version`
and `target-byte-code-version` have set 11.

- Also for last chance if Heroku can't deploy, try this at bottom of your `pom.xml` file.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I already have ```<java.version>11</java.version>```. As for the others, seems you are using IntelliJ right? I'm using STS, which is a bit different. So couldn't find some of those. Anyway, if I go to Project Explorer > Libraries > JRE System Library > it is version 11. On Preferences > Java Compiler > also on version 11. Couldn't find "project language level", neither ```project-byte-code-version``` and ```target-byte-code-version```. Seems those are from IntelliJ. I added maven-compiler-plugin on pom.xml and tried again. Same issue. Heroku continues compiling on version 1.8.

Comment: Yes, I'm using IntelliJ. I had your problem too, but after adding those lines, the error fixed.